# Java - Slick2D/lwjgl get mouse position

Tags: java, position, mouse, lwjgl, slick2d

So, I'm trying to check my mouse position inside of my game window but my program doesn't update the
x and y coordinates correctly. Instead, it only displays a static number for both x and y. I'm pretty 
sure I did set up Slick2D and lwjgl correctly as an empty black box with the FPS counter does appear when I run the application.

Anyways, the below code is displaying "x: -161 y:-1" for whatever reason. How would I fix this so that it displays the correct mouse position?

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class LogIn extends BasicGameState{

public String mouse;

public LogIn(int state){

}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{


}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString(mouse, 50, 50);
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
    int xpos = Mouse.getX();
    int ypos = Mouse.getY();
    mouse = "x: " + xpos + " y: " + ypos; 
}

public int getID(){
    return 1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Input input = gc.getInput();
int xpos = input.getMouseX();
int ypos = input.getMouseY();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. I used the lwjgl.jar from the lwjgl-2.9.2 download folder and it worked.
I guessed using the one that came with Slick2D was buggy or something. Maybe my set up was wrong from the start? Anyways, I got it to work.

Comment: I had the same problem and doing this fixed it for me.